# how does XSLT know to read desired xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to learn this: styling html with XSLT and xml.
Currently I am using php/mysql, which is cumbersome for the xml file I am using. Currently, I import that whole xml file, process it, then dump it to an sql table, then process the table (sorting etc.) at runtime, which is a long process and VERY "Kludgy!". I recently found out, that all this can be accomplished with XSLT applied to XML. The problem, I understand (sorta) how it works, however, after about 3 days of mind numbing searching, I have yet to find:

***how does the xls know to use the file I downloaded remotely (or locally).***

Several suggestions is to add it to the XML file, but not sure if that is right. The xml data has 5,000+ entries.
Example, in another stack over flow topic I found this: but it is the OPPOSITE of what I need:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourxsl.xsl"?>
```

so

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="wine">
```

random site of many I am learning xslt/xml but this too, does not show where the data is coming from. In the above example, how does the XSLT know to use the file that has the wine entries?

Example If I have

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);//$file = remote or local xml file
```

how does XSLT know that this is the data I want. W3 examples are no help. It does a good job explaining xls an dhow it works, but the sample xml file appears to be within the same executing script. I am getting this feeling I cannot see the forest for the trees.

help! totally confused now :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are different APIs for invoking an XSLT transformation. You appear to be using PHP, so your first step is probably to use the API offered by the XSLTProcessor that comes bundled with PHP. This is described here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php

The method XSLTProcessor.transformToXML() is supplied with an input document to be transformed, using the stylesheet previously compiled using XSLTProcessor.importStylesheet().

The reason W3C doesn't have any information on this is that the API is language-specific - if you were invoking a transformation from Java or C# or Javascript you would use a different API.

Incidentally, you should be aware that the version of XSLT supported by PHP's XSLTProcessor is very old (XSLT 1.0, dating back to 1999). If you want to use a more modern version of the language (XSLT 3.0 was published earlier this year), download the Saxon/C product (from www.saxonica.com). This has a PHP interface with an API that is similar but not identical to the built-in XSLTProcessor.

Comment: thank you i'll take a look at this! I'll leave this open for a bit to see if any other options arise for my scenario.  cheers!!

Comment: While researching.. I found this to complement @Michael Kay answer   [XSLTProcessor Example](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php). Just an FYI, the age of the processor will not be an issue as the site, while it has a huge library, is extremely simplistic in it delivery.